# Git hub project _ Learning)

Tags: eclipse, github

I am working on a simple project to learn github. After I worked on my project in eclipse on my local computer, I pushed my project to github for other teammates. A second member of my team pulled this project from github and pushed back to github after making some changes. Now this morning I want to pull this updated project from github to my local machine (eclipse) so I can work on this updated project.
How can I pull this updated project from github to direct into eclipse on my local computer .
I am tried to do:
"git clone [http://github.com/testproject/gitDemo.git"](http://github.com/testproject/gitDemo.git%22) but it is not directly going to eclipse. If I save this project on my machine and then try to import into eclipse I got error message, "can not import, there is already one project exist with same name".
I did not see pull option in eclipse under:
Right click on project - team - Pull

Any suggestions??

Thank you in advance for all your help

Comment: Just do a pull: in Eclipse right-click the project folder and choose _Team > Pull_. Git on the command line is not needed at all, it even does not need to be installed. But if you use Git on the command line, click the _Refresh_ button in the _Git Staging_ view or the _Git Repositories_ view when switching back to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make one point that I'm not certain you do NOT understand, but as I often see this misunderstood, I'll point it out.

You should separate the notion of "git repository" and "project".  When you clone a git repository from github (or bitbucket, or some central repository), you should store it in a directory tree outside of your Eclipse workspace.  You then should right-click on the repository and select "Import..." to create a project from the contents of that repository.

Related to that, you should look for the "Pull" operation on the repository entry, not the project.  I recommend to display the Git Repositories view on the left side, below the Package/Project Explorer, and make sure that you attempt all git operations in that view, instead of the Package Explorer view.

The only detail from your original post that I can address is the error about already having a project with that name.  That error message is not ambiguous at all.  You already had a project with that name. I have no idea whether that project was a copy of the repository that you had somehow already imported, or whether it's an empty project, or what.  You don't provide any information about that.